# How can I add and configure a Driver through a Script?

Tags: python, drivers, properties, shader-nodes

I'm trying to add and configure a driver through a script. so far I have the following script:

```
import bpy
bpy.data.materials.new("Property Dump")
bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].use_nodes=True
prin=bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF']
outputnode=bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes['Material Output']
bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes.remove(prin)
bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes.remove(outputnode)
test=bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeMix")
test.location=(100, 100)


bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].driver_add("default_value")
```

This makes a new material called *Property Dump*, deletes the default nodes, adds a mix node, and gives a default value driver to the first input of the mix node. What I want to know is how to give the driver an expression, add an input variable, make it single property, etc. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can find information about Drivers in Blender's [`Official Documentation`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html) and the [`Driver Panel`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html). You can configure a fully functional driver for your chosen field `bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes["Mix"].inputs[0]` in the following script which is driven in this example by the `scale[0]` property (which is *Scale X*) of the `bpy.data.objects["Cube"]` object, but you can choose any object or property of your interest:

[image]

When you create a driver using the method `add_driver`, it returns an [`FCurve`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurve.html) with a property that contains the `driver`. You can set the driver [`Driver Type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Driver.html#bpy.types.Driver.type) with values *AVERAGE*, *SUM*, *MIN*, *MAX*, & *SCRIPTED* and give it any [`Python Expression`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#expressions) that uses [`Driver Variables`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#driver-variables) created with the method `variables.new()` which returns a [`DriverVariable`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.DriverVariable.html) object that can be setup with a name.

Then you have to configure the driver itself which is in our example the object `bpy.data.objects["Cube"]` by setting the values in the variable's [DriverTargets](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.DriverTarget.html) list. In this case we only have 1 driver target so we retrieve the first element with `v.targets[0]` and set the [`id_type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/id_type_items.html#rna-enum-id-type-items) to `OBJECT` and the [`id`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.DriverTarget.html#bpy.types.DriverTarget.id) to `bpy.data.objects["Cube"]`. But you can have a driver of any type of ID-block [`Id Type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/id_type_items.html#rna-enum-id-type-items). Then specify the `data_path` to use which can be obtained from any property or field in the Blender interface by right clicking any field of interest and selecting *Copy Data Path*. Then just paste the copied *Data Path* in your script.

```
fcurve = bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].driver_add("default_value")

d = fcurve.driver
d.type = "SCRIPTED"
d.expression = "my_var + 0.1"

v = d.variables.new()
v.name = "my_var"

t = v.targets[0]
t.id_type = 'OBJECT'
t.id = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
t.data_path = "scale[0]"
```

Try this entire code:

```
import bpy

bpy.data.materials.new("Property Dump")
bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].use_nodes=True
prin=bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF']
outputnode=bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes['Material Output']
bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes.remove(prin)
bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes.remove(outputnode)
test=bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeMix")
test.location=(100, 100)

fcurve = bpy.data.materials["Property Dump"].node_tree.nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].driver_add("default_value")

d = fcurve.driver
d.type = "SCRIPTED"
d.expression = "my_var + 0.1"

v = d.variables.new()
v.name = "my_var"

t = v.targets[0]
t.id_type = 'OBJECT'
t.id = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
t.data_path = "scale[0]"
```

Comment: still nothing. the documentation says its still called "SCRIPTED" as of 3.4.1

Comment: removing the line gives me the same error for the next line. i think it might be something with another part of my code

Comment: tried it with 3.1.2 same issue

Comment: my script has a lot more code than what i originally sent. ill update the post to include the entire thing which is most likely the issue

Comment: oh alright. i usually limit myself to one question per day as to prevent spamming