# Copy right side bone's constraint parameter as driver and paste it on counterpart of left side bone

Tags: python, scripting, bones, drivers, bone.constraints

There are lots of bones and right side bones and left side bones have same constraint. I always copy right side bones constraint parameter as driver and paste them on same parameter of left side bones constraint. I would like to do it using python.

[image]

For example there are Bone_R and Bone_L and both have copy location constraint. And I tweaked influence parameter of Bone_R's copy location constraint and I do "Copy As New Driver" on the influence parameter and paste the driver on influence parameter of Bone_L's copy location constraint. Is it possible to automate this task using python? At least "Copy As New Driver" command  accesses right side bone's copy location parameter so, I can have bones name and its copy location influence status, then if so I simply change the path (like copy location influence of Bone_R to copy location influence of Bone_L)and paste the driver, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only 1 armature named *Armature* which contains bones named *Bone_R* and *Bone_L*, you can use the following script to add a driver to *Bone_L*'s [`Copy Location Constraint`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/copy_location.html)'s *Influence* parameter which is driven by *Bone_R*'s [`Copy Location Constraint`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/copy_location.html)'s *Influence* parameter:

```
import bpy

armature = bpy.data.objects['Armature']

bone_R = armature.pose.bones['Bone_R']
bone_L = armature.pose.bones['Bone_L']

constraint = next((c for c in bone_L.constraints if c.type == 'COPY_LOCATION'), None)

fc = constraint.driver_add('influence')
d = fc.driver

v = d.variables.new()
v.name = "influence"
target = v.targets[0]
target.id_type = 'OBJECT'
target.id = armature
target.data_path = 'pose.bones["Bone_R"].constraints["Copy Location"].influence'
d.expression = "influence"
```

If you have multiple armatures with this type of bone configuration, just loop through every armature and execute that same script. For more information on using or scripting drivers see [How can I add and configure a Driver through a Script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282146/142292)

Comment: thank you. is it possible to use Blender's "Copy As New Driver" ? I thought it saves something in clipboard and let us paste it on any parameters.

Comment: It's not possible to directly use `bpy.ops.ui.copy_as_driver_button()` and `bpy.ops.anim.paste_driver_button()`. Or at least nobody knows I think. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181797/how-can-i-use-the-copy-as-driver-and-paste-driver-functionality-in-python

Comment: oh. too bad. bpy.ops.ui.copy_as_driver_button() is really useful so I wanted to use it. I've made a script using your script. it makes a new driver to L side bones referencing R side bone's Copy Location, Copy Rotation, Copy Scale, and Transform constraints. very useful. thank you.