# How to set up driver via python script between Custom Properties of objects?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, properties

I want to set up drivers: from Custom Properties of a Camera to Custom Properties of selected object.
[image]

Based on a script from 6 year old post:
[How to put together a driver with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39127/how-to-put-together-a-driver-with-python),
I manage to have this code,

```
import bpy
def add_driver(
        source, target, prop, dataPath,
        index = -1, negative = False, func = ''
    ):
    ''' Add driver to source prop (at index), driven by target dataPath '''

    if index != -1:
        d = source.driver_add( prop, index ).driver
    else:
        d = source.driver_add( prop ).driver

    v = d.variables.new()
    v.name                 = prop
    v.targets[0].id        = target
    v.targets[0].data_path = dataPath

    d.expression = func + "(" + v.name + ")" if func else v.name
    d.expression = d.expression if not negative else "-1 * " + d.expression

#-------------------------------------------- 
ob = bpy.context.active_object
camera = bpy.context.scene.objects['Camera']

prop_name1 = ob.name + "_Opacity"
prop_name2 = ob.name + "_Highlight"


add_driver( ob, camera, prop_name1, prop_name1, -1)
add_driver( ob, camera, prop_name2, prop_name2, -1)
```

but executing it always give me error:

```
"Python: TypeError: bpy_struct.driver_add(): property "FirstCube_Opacity" not found
```

...even if I'm sure that all the objects have proper named Custom Properties. The function of setting up driver works great with other parameters in blender like 'scale'. What Am I doing wrong?

###UPDATE CODE####

Script1 - Creating Custom Properties

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.active_object

prop_name1 = ob.name + "_Opacity"
ob[prop_name1] = 0.0
ob.id_properties_ensure()  # Make sure the manager is updated
property_manager = ob.id_properties_ui(prop_name1)
property_manager.update(min=0.0, max=1.0, soft_min=0.0, soft_max=1.0)

camera = bpy.context.scene.objects['Camera']

prop_name2 = ob.name + "_Opacity"
camera[prop_name2] = 0.0
camera.id_properties_ensure()  # Make sure the manager is updated
property_manager = camera.id_properties_ui(prop_name2)
property_manager.update(min=0.0, max=1.0, soft_min=0.0, soft_max=1.0)
```

Script2 - Setting up driver, "Object_Opacity" CAMERA's Custom Property should drive "Object_Opacity" Object's Custom Property

```
import bpy
def add_driver(
        source, target, prop, dataPath,
        index = -1, negative = False, func = ''
    ):
    ''' Add driver to source prop (at index), driven by target dataPath '''

    if index != -1:
        d = source.driver_add( prop, index ).driver
    else:
        d = source.driver_add( prop ).driver

    v = d.variables.new()
    v.name                 = prop
    v.targets[0].id        = target
    v.targets[0].data_path = dataPath

    d.expression = func + "(" + v.name + ")" if func else v.name
    d.expression = d.expression if not negative else "-1 * " + d.expression
ob = bpy.context.active_object
camera = bpy.context.scene.objects['Camera']

prop_name1 = ob.name + "_Opacity"


add_driver( ob, camera, f'["{prop_name1}"]', f'["{prop_name1}"]', -1)
```

Comment: I think you want to enclose your property name with brackets, since it's a custom property that's how they are accessed : `add_driver( ob, camera, "prop", f'["{prop_name1}"]', -1)`

Comment: Thank You! Small succes! 
Driver is assigned, but it doesn't work :(. The area of value beeing driven is purple, but it's not beeing changing by the Camera's Custom Property.

screen:
https://imgur.com/a/sjQQNVW

Comment: Yeah take notice of the snippet I posted, I replaced the prop name (3rd parameter) to "prop" because a variable name can't have hyphens or brackets in them

Answer (score 0):

Replace `add_driver(ob, camera, prop_name1, prop_name1, -1)`

With `add_driver(ob, camera, "prop", f'["{prop_name1}"]', -1)`

Custom property are accessed with square brackets and double quotes, when regular properties are accessed directly.

In python variable names can't contain brackets nor quotes so I suggest you use `"prop"` string in this case which will create a variable named `prop`.

Comment: In what blender version do you have it running? I tried in 3.0.0 and in  3.2.0 Alpha, and I always get:
"Python: TypeError: bpy_struct.driver_add(): property "prop" not found"

Comment: You need to have the custom property on both the source and target (by the way, in my opinion the two variable names should be swapped inside the function)

Comment: But I have Custom Properties... I did everything ok imo. It looks like just setting up driver (even manually) with made by script Custom Properties is buggy.
I recorded video for you, Can You say if You think so too?
Maybe it's supposed to be reported as a bug.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVFAE1TyckU

Comment: I believe it has to do with the driver not being notified that the value was updated. Could you post your updated code too ?

Comment: The file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B4tpvHLj4Cms7MRyd7ZjLirCKE0n3S42/

First script creates Custom Properties.
Second should assign driver, but it never worked (I tried different parameters on the fly).

Thank you very much for investigating it.

Comment: I'd rather you copy/paste the script in your question, I don't like downloading random files on the internet. I appreciate the amount of effort you put into trying to solve your problem, and I'd like to help you but that requires you describing more extensively your problem inside your question

Comment: Oki, I added update to the question. The first script (creating Custom Properties with min and max values) was created with your help from yesterday. It is nothing more. It's just adds it not only to the object, but also to the Camera.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135911/discussion-between-evilferber-and-gorgious).